# Downloading IBM J9 JDK

Tags: java, ibm-jdk, j9

I have the following questions on IBM J9 JDK/JRE.

1. Does any one know the location where I can download the latest J9 JDK? I googed it and couldn't find the location.
2. What is the relation between IBM J9 JDK and Apache Harmony project?

Thank you.

Comment: You can get IBM JDKs for Linux, AIX and z/OS (OS/390) here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/ IBM JVMs generally aren't free to download & distribute (though check the T&Cs for any products you have purchased).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As McDowell suggested in his comment. You can get the J9 JDK from this link: https://developer.ibm.com/javasdk/downloads/. Specifically..

**Linux** - https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/linux/download.html

**Windows** - To get the JDK for windows is a tricky one. You have to download [IBM Development Package for Eclipse](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/eclipse/index.html). This will give you a eclipse Europa (3.3) version, along with J9 JDK version 1.6.

Previously J9 was the recommended VM for running the harmony class files, as their own version of JVM was incomplete. Have a look at this wiki page.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Harmony

> In the end of November, 2006, the
>   language support provided by these
>   virtual machine was still incomplete,
>   and the build instructions recommended
>   to use IBM's proprietary J9 instead to
>   run the class library test suite.
>   However, this is not necessary anymore
>   (as of July 2007). The DRLVM virtual
>   machine is currently (as of July 2006)
>   under heavy development, so a fast
>   improvement of its features can be
>   expected

Answer (score 2):

1: http://wiki.eclipse.org/J9? - try this

Comment: J9 is more than jusT the ME edition

Answer (score 0):

Official J9 docker images are also available from: https://hub.docker.com/_/ibmjava/